# How to make auto adjusting divs that are pre-set?

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask a question that I wanted to know for some time now..

I'd like to make a website where the divbox's auto adjust when you rezise the windows.. and so they be sized down if another div next to it is inline.

I have made an example of the second question which I will explain.

This picture is how I want the website to look on the first page, so that I can have the content on the left in the bigger div and then the control panel on the right at that size.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2YEw.png

And I want to make it so that when I remove the the sidebar from the actual html, for another page; the content will automatically resize to the full length of the container, i.e.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCwaZ.png

Please help me if you can! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern browsers supports media query `@media` which fires automatically when some conditions are true. [Here is an example in which the div auto adjusts themselves.](https://jsfiddle.net/5m3nLxxs/2/)

To better understand it,

Write following CSS,

```
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

/*To specify extra padding*/
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

/*Just to add visual effect*/
.left-content{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
}

.right-content{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
}
```

What the above CSS does is that it specifies 12 different sizes for a div. Now as you mentioned in your question you want the content on the left bigger compared to the control panel on the right you can specify the left content with `class="col-9"` and the right control panel with `class="col-3"`

```
<div class="col-9 left-content">
   Content on left
</div> 

<div class="col-3 right-content">
   Content on right
</div>
```

Now when the browser is resized and made small the div will automatically adjust themselves.

You can do this via some 3rd party framework used for responsive designs. I would recommend Bootstrap for it. But if you want to do it the hard way i.e. on your own then you can use the above css.

Comment: Alright, and then if I have on a page without the sidebar.. i.e. col-3; I'd just need to change the col-9 to col-12 I'm guessing?

Comment: @AlexRickells yeah you are right, just make sure that all the div that you want to appear adjacent to each other should make a total of 12  Eg. if you want to add a control panel on left side of the scree too then your classes should be .col-3 .col-6 .col-3 (3+6+3 = 12)

Comment: @TripleS How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it 'disapear' by using jQuery, something like this:

`$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.triger').click(function(){

    $('.container .b').toggle();

    if ($('.b').is(':visible')){
        $('.a').css('width','70%');
    } else { 
        $('.a').css('width','100%');
    }

});
```

});`

It should be something like this: [HERE IS A EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4bsdL04j/)

Comment: No, I don't want it to disappear, I want the content div ( The left one ) to expand to its full size when I remove the sidebar ( the right one ) from the page, so it isn't there anymore.