# change to Responsive Site

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design, responsiveness

i have used on my site Width and  height like

```
 <table  width="800px"  height="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="leftborder"/>
```

i have to changed this code media query for responsive but its not working i set background color red when i re size my browser its showing color only not in resize  content

[image]

My code:

```
<style type="text/css">

  @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width : 780px)
       {
           .leftborder
           {
               background-color:skyblue;
           }


.rightborder { 
border-right: 1px solid #000000; 
} 

.leftborder { 
border-left: 1px solid #000000; 
border-right: 1px solid #000000; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; 

border-style: thin; 
} 


.style2 {font-size: xx-small}

.descriptor_row
{
background:#003366;
font-size:x-small;
color:#FFFFFF;
border:#FFFFFF;
} 


BODY { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:160%;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    background: url(images/gradient2.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    background-color:#FFF; 
}       


table.leftborder{

    align:"right";
    width:800px ! Important;
    height:600px ! Important;

}

            }



/* MOBILE LANDSCAPE */
       @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 780px)
       {
.leftborder        {
               background-color:blue;
           }

}



/* SMALL TABLET */
       @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width:780px)
       {
           .leftborder
           {
               background-color:green;
           }

       }



/* TABLET/NETBOOK */
       @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 780px)
       {
           .leftborder
           {
               background-color:yellow;
           }

}



.rightborder { 
border-right: 1px solid #000000; 
} 

.leftborder { 
border-left: 1px solid #000000; 
border-right: 1px solid #000000; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; 

border-style: thin; 
} 


.style2 {font-size: xx-small}

.descriptor_row
{
background:#003366;
font-size:x-small;
color:#FFFFFF;
border:#FFFFFF;
} 


BODY { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:160%;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    background: url(images/gradient2.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    background-color:#FFF; 
}       




</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow(winName)
{
    window.open(winName,"FAQs", "width=950,height=650,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no,left=100,top=100,screenX=100,location=no,screenY=100");
}
</script>
</head>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" RIGHTMARGIN="0">

<table  width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="design"/ >
   <tr>
       <td align="center">
         <table  width="800px"  height="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="leftborder"/>
              <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

              <td colspan="2"  style="background-image:url('site_conf/images/det_banner.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;" width="100%" height="100" align="right" />

              <?php
              if(!is_null($sid)&&$session_error=="none")
              {
                    $_SESSION['lms_username']=$lms_username;
                    ?><TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="190" >
                    <TR>
                        <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000">Logged in as: <B><?php echo $lms_username; ?></B></TD>
                    </TR>
                        <?php
                        if($lms_groups=="on" && $lms_user_group!=""){
                        ?>
                        <TR>
                            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php echo"$lms_gtitle: "; if($lms_groups=="on"){echo"<B>$lms_user_group</B>";}?></TD>        
                        </TR>   
                        <TR>
                            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php echo "$lms_sgtitle: "; if($lms_groups=="on"){echo"<B>$lms_user_subgroup</B>";}?></TD>

                        </TR>   
                        <tr>
                            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php if($section=="reports" && $report){echo"<A HREF='index.php?section=reports&sid=$sid'>Back to Detailed Reports Section";}?></FONT></TD>
                        </tr>
                        <?php }?>

                    </TABLE>
                    <?php   
               }
              ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" height="20" background="images/bg.gif">
                      <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                         <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <TD align="right"><?php
                if(!is_null($sid)&&$session_error=="none")
                {
                ?><a style=""  href="index.php?section=<?php echo $section; ?>&logout=YES&sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>"><img src="images/logout.gif" border="0" align="ABSMIDDLE" alt="Click here to Log Out"></a><?php
                }
                ?></TD>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td>
              </tr>
             <tr>
                <?php
                if(is_null($sid)||$session_error!="none")
                {
                    $nav_display = 'display: none';
                }
                ?>
                <td valign="top" style=" <?php echo $nav_display; ?> ">
                <!---------BEGIN SIDE NAV TABLE------------->
                <table width="198" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                  <tr valign="top" bordercolor="#FFFFFF"> 
                     <td width="198" bordercolor="#FFFFFF"><?php          
                     if((!is_null($sid)&&$session_error=="none"))
                     {
                        include($dir_components."navbar2.php");

                     }
                     ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="boxcontent" VALIGN="TOP" >
    <?php 

    include($mysection);
    ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr width="200;">
</body>
</html>
```

added  image what i am getting ?please help me any advise ?

Comment: its not possible to say anything without checking your coding, is it possible to add your codes in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742346/how-to-make-auto-adjusting-divs-that-are-pre-set/30743284#30743284

Comment: k  @RoySonasish wii add jsfiddle

Comment: thanks@SaumilSoni i will check  that question

Comment: @RoySonasish my  code totall so many files there ..now  i have remain css file here?

Answer (score 0):

On your media queries you have just changed the color and how do you supposed to get responsive design. You need to change other properties like `width` or `height` to adjust on that respective screen size. Or there are other options for you, like responsive tables plugins or if you want to fix via media queries you need to first decide how you wanna display on specific screen size, options are like **scrollable tables** or **breaking table headings into blocks and columns below** and so on then only you go to media queries to adjust as accordingly.

Comment: thanks @K.C i will change my width and height  after that assign media query  thank you